# How to make combineLatest send a value when one of its publishers haven't emitted yet?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

I'm trying to use `CombineLatest` to publish a value whenever one of two publishers change. It just happens that one of these publishers is an *objectWillChange* property of an *ObservedObject* (`PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>`).

```swift
Publishers.CombineLatest(
    settings.objectWillChange,
    $aPublishedProperty)
    .sink(receiveValue: { _, _ in
        // Do something…
    })
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

The issue here is as long as this object don't change, *CombineLatest* will never emit. And I actually don't care about its *void* value. I'm just putting it here so that if it ever changes in the future, then my *sink* will get called again.

How can I trigger CombineLatest without an initial value? i.e: only with the change of `aPublishedProperty`?

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice operator called `prepend(_:)` that you can use to make a publisher emit an initial value.

In my case, all I had to do was to add `.prepend(())` to `objectWillChange`.

```swift
Publishers.CombineLatest(
    settings.objectWillChange.prepend(()), // ⬅️ Useful stuff here
    $aPublishedProperty)
    .sink(receiveValue: { _, _ in
        // Do something…
    })
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

See it in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204741-prepend)